# FFmpeg - can't use -pattern_type option

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg

I'm trying to use FFmpeg to create a video from a series of images, named `snapshot-00001.jpg`, `snapshot-00002.jpg`, and so on, by using the command `ffmpeg -f image2 -r 10 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' output.mp4`. However, I'm faced with the error:

```
$ ffmpeg -f image2 -r 10 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' output.mp4
ffmpeg version 0.10.9-7:0.10.9-1~quantal1 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Oct  4 2013 06:35:56 with gcc 4.7.2
  configuration: --arch=i386 --disable-stripping --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='7:0.10.9-1~quantal1' --libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --enable-shared --disable-static
  avutil      configuration: --arch=i386 --disable-stripping --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='7:0.10.9-1~quantal1' --libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-doc
  avcodec     configuration: --arch=i386 --disable-stripping --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='7:0.10.9-1~quantal1' --libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-doc
  avformat    configuration: --arch=i386 --disable-stripping --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='7:0.10.9-1~quantal1' --libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-doc
  avdevice    configuration: --arch=i386 --disable-stripping --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='7:0.10.9-1~quantal1' --libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-doc
  avfilter    configuration: --arch=i386 --disable-stripping --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='7:0.10.9-1~quantal1' --libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-doc
  swscale     configuration: --arch=i386 --disable-stripping --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='7:0.10.9-1~quantal1' --libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-doc
  swresample  configuration: --arch=i386 --disable-stripping --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='7:0.10.9-1~quantal1' --libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-doc
  postproc    configuration: --arch=i386 --disable-stripping --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='7:0.10.9-1~quantal1' --libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-doc
  libavutil      51. 35.100 / 51. 35.100
  libavcodec     53. 61.100 / 53. 61.100
  libavformat    53. 32.100 / 53. 32.100
  libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
  libavfilter     2. 61.100 /  2. 61.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0.  6.100 /  0.  6.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
Unrecognized option 'pattern_type'
Failed to set value 'glob' for option 'pattern_type'
```

I've just made a fresh FFmpeg install from [here](https://launchpad.net/~jon-severinsson/+archive/ffmpeg); I did `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jon-severinsson/ffmpeg`, followed by `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`, but still get the same error. Use of the option is stated on the manual [here](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html), but for some reason I can't use it.

EDIT: included full command line output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FFmpeg PPA supplies older versions, which may not have the option. Generally, it's not recommended to install ffmpeg from distribution packages – rather compile it yourself or download [a static build](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) from their homepage.

You don't necessarily have to use the glob patterns – an input file like `ffmpeg -i 'snapshot-%05d.jpg' output.mp4` should also work.

Comment: I just tried `ffmpeg -f image2 -r 10 -i 'snapshot-%5d.jpg' output.mp4` and it works! However, would it still work if the numbers jump? e.g. I have the files `snapshot-00001.jpg`, `snapshot-00003.jpg`, `snapshot-00005.jpg`.

Comment: Sorry no, your command doesn't seem to work. It creates the .mp4, but it seems like its only 1 frame long. The file size is only 16kb, and the thumbnail is the same as the first frame. I only just realised because I tried to play the video.

Comment: Please try again with a recent version!

Comment: I used a static version of ffmpeg (5th Nov), and your command works! However, if there're corrupted files midway, it ends prematurely. The first 16 or so images for me are corrupted, so I actually copied and pasted the first working image and renamed it to have numbers 1 through 16 to make the full video. I tried again with the `-pattern_type glob` option, and it solved my problem! :)

Comment: Great, I'm glad it worked for you!